# Laravel 4 updating all records with array gives me parameter mismatch error

Tags: arrays, laravel-4, eloquent

Trying to update each row of a table with a multidimensional array created from querying another database.

The array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [community_id] => ap
            [floorplan_code] => ap1-1a
            [name] => 33flat
            [hidden] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [community_id] => ap...
```

Here is the code I'm using in an attempt to update:

```
$floorPlan = new Floorplan; //create new instance
$floorPlan->get();  //get all rows
$floorPlan->update($floorplanMappedArray);  //map db columns to array and update
```

Error message: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array.

Comment: what are the table fields you have for `Floorplan`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter mismatch came from the fact that I was trying to shove a multidimensional array into a single row.  Therefore, I needed a foreach loop to index through the multidimensional array.

I thought that there was a magical way to use the update() method in the same way that the insert() method is used.  Apparently, there is not.

Here is the code that solved the parameter mismatch error:

```
foreach ($floorplanMappedArray as $floorPlan) {
    Floorplan::where('floorplan_code', $floorPlan['floorplan_code'])->update($floorPlan);
}
```